# Multiple updates in one sql query

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have a table in H2 DB

```
Order
-------- 
id (key)
MarketId1
MarketId2
MarketId3
ListName1
ListName2
ListName3
```

From XML I'm getting list of ListOrder

```
public final class ListOrder
{
     public long listId;
     public String Name;
}
```

So I have 3 prepared statements

```
"UPDATE Order set " + ListName1 + " = ? WHERE " + MarketId1 + " = ?"
"UPDATE Order set " + ListName2 + " = ? WHERE " + MarketId2 + " = ?"
"UPDATE Order set " + ListName3 + " = ? WHERE " + MarketId3 + " = ?"
```

The in a method I prepare a list of PreparedStament to execute

```
final PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY1);
final PreparedStatement statement2 = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY2);
final PreparedStatement statement3 = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY3);

    for (ListOrder listOrder: listOrders)
    {
        statement1.setString(1, listOrder.Name);
        statement1.setLong(2, listOrder.listId);
        statement1.addBatch();

        statement2.setString(1, listOrder.Name);
        statement2.setLong(2, listName.listId);
        statement2.addBatch();

        statement3.setString(1, listName.Name);
        statement3.setLong(2, listOrder.listId);
        statement3.addBatch();
    }

    return new ArrayList<PreparedStatement>(){{add(statement1); add(statement2); add(statement3);}};
```

I'm a SQL noob. Is there any better way of doing it? I assume that MarketId 1 2 3 could be the same. ListNames could be null (there will be at least one)

UPDATE:
In code I would write something like this (prob change to HashMap)

```
for (ListOrder listOrder: listOrders)
{
    for(Order order : orders)
    {
         if(order.marketID1 == listOrder.listID)
              order.listName1 = listOrder.Name; //break if no dups
         if(order.marketID2 == listOrder.listID)
              order.listName2 = listOrder.Name;
         if(order.marketID3 == listOrder.listID)
              order.listName3 = listOrder.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the statement to fill `ListName` and `MarketId`?

Comment: MarketId is there I just need to Update ListNames depending on marketID{1,2,3} is equal to listID

Comment: You can set them outside of the loop still.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you ask the question - is there a problem you want to solve? For example, is it too slow? Generally, your code looks OK, but it has a few typos and I don't understand why you use `addBatch` and why you return a list of PreparedStatements instead of executing them.

Comment: @ThomasMueller typos are prob cause I edit the question to reduce the extra information. I'm returning it just to execute all statements in one place. I use addBatch because I misunderstand what it does. The question is mostly about how to refactor this code in something more concise.

Comment: I'm confused. why you don't understand my use of `addBatch`, say I have ListOrder with 9 elements Therefor I should have  27 possible updates so I should add batch to each query e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309317/considerations-regarding-addbatchstring

Comment: @lukas Of course you can use `addBatch` but at some point you have to call `executeBatch` and you didn't show you do. What I mean, I wouldn't worry about `addBatch`/`executeBatch`, but instead just call `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update comma separated

```
UPDATE <TABLE>
SET COL1 = <VAL1>,
COL2= <VAL2>
WHERE <CONDITION>
```

Is it this what you expect as one update query?

Comment: What will be condition then?

Comment: MarketId1 = val and MarketId2 = val and MarketId1 = val as you said they have same values..

Comment: could be the same (most likely not)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to update the same record, then there is no way to do this easily or efficiently in a single query. Otherwise, assuming this is the desired result, you could use an OR (or an AND if that is desired) statement such as:

```
UPDATE Order 
SET ListName1=?, ListName2=?, ListName3=? 
WHERE MarketId1=? OR  MarketId2=? OR MarketId3=?
```

You might also consider updating your table to use a one:many relationship which might make your queries easier. For example:

```
Order
-------- 
id (key)
name
etc

Market_List
--------
id (key)
order_id (fk)
market
listname
```

Comment: but that is different behavior. If any of MarketIds match then update all ListNames.

Comment: precisely. If you want them  ALL to match, use an AND. It's hard to see what you're really trying to do from your question. Honestly, you're not incurring much load by running 3 simple queries. If they are related, you may consider wrapping them in a transaction though.